# Python: Why do an unbound method with two params behave other than a class method?

Tags: python

In this piece of code:

```
def fa(a,b): 
    print a
    print b
    print " fa called"

class A:
    @classmethod
    def fa(a,b): 
        print a
        print b
        print " A.fa called"
class B:
    def __init__(s,a):
        s.a = a

obj1 = B(A.fa)
obj1.a("xxxx")

obj2 = B(fa)
obj2.a("xxxx")
```

Output:

```
__main__.A
xxxx
A.fa called
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
   obj2.a("xxxx")
TypeError: fa() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Why is the free method "fa" not receiving the "self" as a first parameter? The bound method A.fa behaves as expected.

Comment: Looks like I've found the answer after a litte research myself: http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm

Answer (score 3):

The bound method `A.fa` receives `A` as the first parameter because it is a class method of `A`.  No matter how you call this function it will always receive `A` as the first parameter.

The free method `fa` is not bound, so the only arguments it will receive are the ones that are passed in.  No matter how you call this function, it will never receive parameters other than the ones that are passed in.

This behavior is different from a language like JavaScript, where how the method is called determines the context.  In Python the implicit argument passing (similar to JavaScript context) is determined at the function definition time, and that binding or lack thereof will always be used for that function regardless of how it is called.

If you want to dynamically bind a free method you can do this using [`types.MethodType`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.MethodType), for example:

```
def fa(x):
    print x

class B: pass

>>> obj1 = B()
>>> obj1.a = MethodType(fa, obj1)
>>> obj1.a()  # obj1.a behaves like an instance method bound to obj1
<__main__.B instance at 0x7f0589baf170>
>>> obj1.a2 = MethodType(fa, B)
>>> obj1.a2() # obj1.a2 acts like a class method bound to B
__main__.B
```

Answer (score 1):

Because doing `obj2.a = fa` does not make `a` (`fa`) a method of `obj2`:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def meth(self, x, y):
...         print x, y
... 
>>> 
>>> a = A()
>>> 
>>> a.meth
<bound method A.meth of <__main__.A object at 0x10e281950>> # Method
>>>
>>> def fn(x, y):
...     print x, y
... 
>>> 
>>> fn
<function fn at 0x10e287140>
>>> a.fn = fn
>>> 
>>> a.fn
<function fn at 0x10e287140>  # Not a method, still a function
```